# How do I compress data points in time-series using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, time-series

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to compress time-series data in MATLAB.

I have some data sets of pupil size, which were gathered during 1 sec with 25,000 points for each trial(I'm still not sure whether it is proper to call the data 'timeseries'). What I'd like to do from now is to compare them with another data, and I need to compress the number of points into about 10,000 or less, minimizing loss of the information. Are there any ways to do it?

I've tried to search how to do this, but all that I could find out was the way to smooth the data or to compress digital images, which were already done or not useful to me.

• The data sets simply consist of pupil diameter, changing as time goes. For each trial, 25,000 points of data were gathered during 1 sec, that means 1 point denotes the pupil diameter measured for 0.04msec. What I want to do is just to adjust this data into 0.1 msec/point; however, I'm not sure whether I can apply techniques like FFT in this case because it is the first time that I handle this kind of data. I appreciate your advices again.

Comment: If you describe your data in a bit more detail we might see if PCA or other dimension reduction techniques are appropriate.  Of course, something simple such as a running average ('window' averaging) using the mean or median may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

A standard data compression technique with time series data is to take the fast Fourier transform and use the smallest frequency amplitudes to represent your data (calculate the power spectrum). You can compare data using these frequency amplitudes, though for the to lose the least amount of information you would want to use the frequencies with the largest amplitudes -- but then it becomes tricky to compare the data... [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/sunspots.html) is the standard Matlab tutorial on FFT. Some other possibilities include:
-ARMA models
-Wavelets

Check out [this paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.pdf) on the "SAX" method, a modern approach for time-series compression -- it also discusses classic time-series compression techniques.